# Excel - Can you limit how many times a user changes the value in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, can you limit how many times a user makes a change to a cell? I want the user to make no more than 2 changes to a cell. Should the user need to make additional changes, they would have to email me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: even if you do implement this it will require users being honest to work. Your file is going to need to be distributed as an xlsm, a user could save that out as xlsx, drop your macros, and over write your original file. Is this accessible from a network drive?

Comment: Do you mean limit to two changes while in the same session with Excel open, or two times ever? Just curious, but what is in the cell that you want the limit for?

Answer (score 2):

To do this method you will need a few things

- Make a sheet called `locks`
- Make your locks sheet `very hidden`.  I put this code in the Workbook_Open even in Thisworkbook

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      Sheets("locks").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
  End Sub
  ```
- in all the sheets you want this effect to happen, `right click> format cells.. > Protection > Locked = false`. Then Protect the sheet. This means that whenever a user hits your threshold the code will unprotect the sheet, lock the cell, the protect again. unlocked cells can be edited like normal but locked cells are read only
- Put this in a standard module

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Public updateThreshold  As Integer


  Public Sub CanUpdate(Target As Range)
      If ThisWorkbook.noEvents Then Exit Sub
      '''------------
      updateThreshold = 2 'change me as you need
      '''---------------
      Dim ws As Worksheet, searchRange As Range
      Dim rangeCol As Integer, updateCountCol As Integer, prevValueCol As Integer, updateDateCol As Integer
      rangeCol = 1
      updateCountCol = 2
      prevValueCol = 3
      updateDateCol = 4

      Set ws = Worksheets("locks")
       Dim tgtAddress As String
      tgtAddress = Target.Address(external:=True)

      Set searchRange = ws.Range("A:A").Find(tgtAddress)

      If searchRange Is Nothing Then
          Set searchRange = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(rowoffset:=1)
          searchRange = tgtAddress
          searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateCountCol) = 1
          searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=prevValueCol) = Target
          searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateDateCol) = Now
      Else
          If searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateCountCol) < updateThreshold Then
              searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateCountCol) = searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateCountCol) + 1
              searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=prevValueCol) = Target
              searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateDateCol) = Now
          End If
          If searchRange.Offset(columnoffset:=updateCountCol) = updateThreshold Then
              Target.Worksheet.Unprotect  'here is where you'd need to use a password if need be
              Target.Locked = True
              Target.Worksheet.Protect    'use a password if need be
          End If
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

What this doesn't do is the month thing mentioned in the comments. If I have time I will come back to that.

You can call this code like `updateThreshold  target` in every sheet's `change` event

Answer (score 1):

If your users aren't wizards, and yourself are one, I'll suggest a way you could achieve that. It may be a little bit elaborate, but it'd accomplish the trick.

**Simple steps :**

1. Use a `xlVeryHidden` sheet as a database for the cells modified. Put the modification-counter in the respective cells.
2. Update the "database" everytime the `Worksheet_Change` function fires
3. Fire an alert and cancel modification if the count is above limit permitted
4. Store the date of the first modification in the very last cell of the table and clear the table when a modification is made 1 month after that date.
5. (Optional) Add a password protection to the VBA project